# PHP or javascript: Flip order of text rows (not MySQL)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I flip the order of text

```
$string = 'last row
something inbetween
first row';
```

Result should be:

```
first row
something inbetween
last row
```

Note this is no A-Z ordering, just flipping it.

Is it possible? A solution in PHP, javascript or jquery would be welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string and reverse the array:

```
$array = explode("\n", $string);
$array = array_reverse($array);
$string = implode("\n", $array);
```

Edit: no one wrote an javascript solution (same logic as php script):

```
var string = string.split("\n").reverse().join("\n");
```

Edit: an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ceKyF/

Comment: Why don't you use "\n"? Your style is a bit ugly.

Comment: I edited my answer, but: In the question the same style as mine was used. What if he doesn't use Windows and he's editor don't use \n but \r ? Why the downvote?

Comment: Windows use "\r\n" by default, Linux use "\n". They're the most common cases. In both cases splitting and joining with "\n" will be fine. It's not so bad to write large string with line breaks, but it's bad to write a single line break as line break.

Answer (score 3):

You could explode the string into an array, reverse it and put it back together:

```
$a=explode("\n",$string);
$string=implode("\n",array_reverse($a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You only got PHP answers, here is a javascript one:

```
// Split the string into an array
var arr = string.split( '\n' )

// Reverse the array
arr.reverse()

// Join the array back into a string
string = arr.join( '\n' )
```

This can be done in one line:

```
string = string.split( '\n' ).reverse().join( '\n' )
```

Comment: I wrote an javscript answer?!

Comment: It was. You submitted your answer 3 minutes ago, my edit was about 10 minutes ago. But I think it's okay, yours is more detailed.

Comment: Well, I didn't see it then :)